# Search good Typo3 training courses in Germany

Tags: typo3

I'm in Germany and I'd be glad that someone from Germany could give me some hints for following issue:

I've been using Typo3 for nearly two years. Now I'd like to deepen my knowledge and skills of Typo3, and want to attend a training course / seminar / workshop or something like that.

In fact I've gained much experience in following topics:
- Grundlagen Serverumgebung
- Apache, PHP und MySQL installieren
- Systemarchitektur & Installation von Instanzen
- Das Backend von TYPO3
- Benutzerverwaltung
- Templating mit Fluid
- Extensionbenutzung
- Extensionmanager
- Extensionprogrammierung (Extbase, Fluid)

I think I'd deepen my knowledge at least in following subjects:
- Systemtuning und Systemoptimierung
- TYPO3 konfigurieren
- TypoScript & Templating

Could anyone from Germany or familiar with the Typo3-training in Germny give me some suggestions? Which courses or schools are good in Germany?

Thanks.

Comment: Please translate your question into English. As already stated in the answers, SO is not a good place to ask these types of questions. These types of questions will usually get downvoted. Ask on Slack.

Comment: See also Wolfgang Wagner Video training, look here for a review: https://www.sgalinski.de/typo3-agentur/technik/wolfgang-wagners-videotraining-zu-typo3-8-lts-ein-review/

Answer (score 0):

stack**overflow** is not the right place for this kind of questions.
A little hint in advance: [The only correct spelling is TYPO3](https://typo3.org/project/brand/spelling-typo3/)

The best you should do is to use a search engine with "TYPO3 training" or "TYPO3 Schulung" and I bet you will find a lot of results. There are many training courses with fixed content, but there are also individual training courses available (but mostly for companies).
Another possibility is to study the [TYPO3 Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/).
Maybe you should visit the [TYPO3 Slack](https://my.typo3.org/index.php?id=35) and ask for experiences with a special TYPO3 training in the #german-group channel.